# Why is over flow occuring in this example?

Tags: binary, overflow, signed

This is the statement I read online.

> If x and y have opposite signs (one is negative, the other is
>   non-negative), then the sum will never overflow.

But when adding -6 (Binary after two's compliment: `11010`) and +9 (Binary : `01001`), the answer is overflow: `100011`. Which means I was adding two numbers in 5 bits but answer is in 6 bits.

According to the above statement the two numbers with opposite signs will not overflow so then why is this answer an overflow?

**Edit:**  Another question that comes to my mind is that if i am using 5-bits to add -6 and +9 in binary, and the answer I am getting is in 6-bits, then is that an overflow? How can it be detected?

Comment: I would imagine they're talking about overflowing a byte, or a word length on the architecture they're discussing.

Comment: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Comb/overflow.html

Comment: @alex can you answer my edited question?